# SQL Access, Concatenate fields within query

Tags: sql, ms-access

is it possible to concatenate fields in my query using sql access(querying using excel).

My current query is :

```
 Select *
 FROM [table$]
```

But how do I add a new field which concatenates `colA&"|"&colB&"|"&colC&"|"&colD`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to understand the expression; just add it to the `select`:

```
select t.*, (t.colA & "|" & t.colB & "|" & t.colC & "|" & t.colD) as new_field
from [table$] as t;
```

Comment: or you could use dynamic sql, but potato puhtahtoe

Comment: Thanks! worked, but seemed like i needed to put colA in [] like `[colA]` , also can I add a where query to query this new field?

Comment: @excelguy. . . You can add filtering in a `where` clause.  But `new_field` is not available unless you use a subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , would you be able to help me with this? Having trouble, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683970/where-condition-in-sql-with-newly-created-field