# where condition in sql with newly created field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query, why cant I get my where clause to work? The value does exist in the table.

```
 Select B.*, B.[RF attribute1] & "|" & B.[RF attribute2] & "|" & B.[RF attribute3] & "|" & B.[RF attribute4] as new_field 
FROM [Black$] as B 
where new_field = "Stack|over||flow"
```

error message is `No value given for one or more required paramters`

**Edit, Actual data:**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| RF attribute1 | RF attribute2 | RF attribute3 | RF attribute4 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| BONDZERO      | AUD           |               | MID           |
| BONDZERO      | AUD           |               | MID           |
| SWAPZERO      | AUD           |               | MID           |
| SWAPZERO      | AUD           |               | MID           |
```

which will create a new field like so:

```
+-------------------+
|     new_field     |
+-------------------+
| BONDZERO|AUD||MID |
| BONDZERO|AUD||MID |
| SWAPZERO|AUD||MID |
| SWAPZERO|AUD||MID |
+-------------------+
```

Now i am trying to use the where clause `BONDZERO|AUD||MID` so it only returns the first 2 rows.

Comment: Because when `where` is processed, the alias is not known yet, so you'll have to repeat the column definition in total. Also, please provide a better error description in future. Stating that you can't get something to work is usually not very helpful, an error message is helpful.

Comment: Wrap it in a subquery.

Comment: The new field cannot `= "Stackoverflow"` because it has at least three vertical bars in it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , the value really does have bars, just for the example i used stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm not sure how null's are handled in this case, but if they follow SQL standard (which I suspect) then `'something' + null = null`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger , but when I concatenate only the fields and data are shown correctly. Now when I add the where clause, I am not getting the limited set of data I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Access thinks you are trying to pass `new_field` as a parameter.

You need to rephrase your `WHERE` clause verbosely:

```
Select B.*, B.[RF attribute1] & "|" 
          & B.[RF attribute2] & "|" 
          & B.[RF attribute3] & "|" 
          & B.[RF attribute4] as new_field 
FROM [Black$] as B 
where       B.[RF attribute1] & "|" 
          & B.[RF attribute2] & "|" 
          & B.[RF attribute3] & "|" 
          & B.[RF attribute4] = "Stack|over||flow"
```

Comment: the query itself doesnt return an error, but it doesnt do the where clause filtering, just returns the full set with the new field.

Comment: With the example you gave in your question, this solution should work as listed unless your data / code is somehow varying dramatically from the listed example. You would need to post actual code and/or actual data to solve any problems you *may* still be having.

Comment: I can say I am querying a .csv file and bringing in the data from this sheet into another sheet in excel but trying to filter it down so the file isnt so large. But the data is the same just not filtering.

Comment: @excelguy ... Please provide *actual* data. Possibly your `WHERE` filter has special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
select b.*
from (Select B.*, B.[RF attribute1] & "|" & B.[RF attribute2] & "|" & B.[RF attribute3] & "|" & B.[RF attribute4] as new_field 
      from [Black$] as B 
     ) as b
where new_field = "Stack|over||flow";
```